# Svnkit with Ant - endless repeat logging in with wrong username or password

Tags: svn, ant, svnkit, ant-contrib

i have a problem with my ant script.
I try to access a svn repository via svnkit and everything is working.
But when I try the connection with a wrong username or password, svnkit endless repeats trying to log in, until the connection is established (what never will happen).

I noticed that svncommandline doesnt have that problem, as it instantly prints an error.
But I would like to have a solution for svnkit, since you dont need svncommandline installed.

My code is like:

```
<ac:trycatch>
    <try>
        <svnSetting javahl="false" svnkit="true" failonerror="true" username="${svn.username}" password="${svn.password}" id="svn.settingsList" />
        <svn refid="svn.settingsList">
            <list Url="${srcUrl}" property="sysDir" onlyNames="true" delimiter="/"/>
        </svn>
    </try>
    <catch>
        <fail message="ERROR accessing SVN"/>
    </catch>
</ac:trycatch>
```

Is there any possible solution with svnkit?

Comment: What is the version of SVNKit?

Comment: What happens if you remove the trycatch block? (That is not part of standard ANT).

Comment: the SVNKit is part of SvnAnt Version 1.3.1.
Removing the trycatch block doesnt fix the problem (actually I cant see anything changed).